# How to capture final output of an interactive python script within a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, variable-assignment, python-interactive

I created a command line interface with [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) to a [client](https://github.com/mfleader/snappyCLI) for an http [server](https://github.com/openshift-scale/snappy-data-server).

This starts an interactive login that displays prompts for username, and then password. If valid, it echoes the authorization token to standard output.

```sh
$ snappy login
```

```sh
Username:
Password:
```

How does one capture the last output in a shell script? I've tried a basic subshell:

```sh
token=$(snappy login)
```

But then `token` captures `Username: Password: <authorization token>`, and no text is displayed to standard output.

My current choice:

```sh
script -qc 'snappy login'
token=$(tail -1 typescript)
rm typescript
```

Bottom 13 lines removed because they only contained the token characters:

```sh
$ snappy login 2>&1 | hexdump -C
myemail@mail.com
00000000  55 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65  3a 20 50 61 73 73 77 6f  |Username: Passwo|

00000010  72 64 3a 20 65 79 4a 30  65 58 41 69 4f 69 4a 4b  |rd: eyJ0eXAiOiJK|
```

Comment: Please add output of `snappy login 2>&1 | hexdump -C` to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
token=$(snappy login | cut -d':' -f3)
```

`cut -d':' -f3` <-- Use `:`  as delimiter and print 3rd field

Comment: Possibly the output has a leading space.

Comment: I suggest to replace `cut -d':' -f3` with `awk -F ': ' '{print $3}'` to use `: ` as field separator.

Comment: Thank you, this works to get the token, but the subshell is not displaying the prompts.